# How to separate the array items in my list of actors?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, join, react-link

I am trying to separate the displayed list of actors (which will also act as a link to the actors bio page) that each movie will have in my "netflix-like" app with a comma followed by a space between each actor. What I currently have now tells me that the ".join()" method in not a function. How can I fix this?

```
{movie.Actors.map(actor => <Link to={`/actors/${actor.Name}`} className="value">{actor.Name.join(", ")}</Link>)}
```

Thanks!

Comment: join is a method found on arrays. actor.Name is a string I presume.

Comment: Yeah it is, I originally had this: <Link to={`/actors/${movie.Actors.map(actor => actor.Name)}`} className="value">{movie.Actors.map(actor => actor.Name).join(", ")}</Link> but it returned all the actors as one link instead of three separate ones. I updated the code to the posting above but it somehow becomes a string somewhere along the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join jsx with comma like this:

```
{movie.Actors.map((actor) => (
      <Link key={actor.Name} to={`/actors/${actor.Name}`} className="value">
        {actor.Name}
      </Link>
    )).reduce((prev, curr) => [prev, ", ", curr])}
```

You can take a look at [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-kepler-5rqvv?file=/src/App.js) for live working example.